# How to make 'git push' work like 'git push origin branch'?

Tags: git, git-remote

Here's a git status showing that I have one commit ready to be pushed:

```
$ git status
# On branch develop
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But then trying `git push` doesn't work:

`$ git push
Everything up-to-date`

Even when I use `git branch develop --set-upstream-to origin/develop`, `git push` still says 'Everything up-to-date'.

How can I force the behavior of `git push` to match `git push origin branch`?

**New information:**
I believe this to be unique to this repository as other repositories on my machine have 'git push' working fine.

**New information (2):**
.git/config file of the project in question:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = false
[gitflow "branch"]
        master = master
        develop = develop
[gitflow "prefix"]
        feature = feature/
        release = release/
        hotfix = hotfix/
        support = support/
        versiontag = 
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://obfuscated.unfuddle.com/git/obfuscated_ob/
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        push = refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
[branch "develop"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/develop
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Mostly just curious: if you run `git ls-remote origin` what branches turn up?  Is `develop` not there?  (If so, that explains the output, but then I wonder how you got `origin/develop`.)

Comment: Please add the output of `git --version` and `git config push.default`.

Comment: @torek develop does show up when running `git ls-remote origin`

Comment: @michas `git --version` yields `git version 1.8.3.4 (Apple Git-47)` and `git config push.default` yields `simple`.

Comment: I'm pretty stumped at this point.  I suggest trying `git push -v` to get a little more verbosity, or `env GIT_TRACE=1 git push -v` for even more, but I'm not sure it will help.

Comment: `git push -v` references master instead of develop! Weird because I know I tried `--set-upstream-to`

Comment: @kraftydevil Have you checked the actual Git config file? You can find it at `.git/config`. See what is set under `[branch "develop"]`.

Comment: develop looks fine in the config file. The push key under `[remote "origin"]` only references master though. Should there be more than one?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the config? You can obfuscate the url if you don't want to share that.

Comment: $ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master for more detail. Also what is the output from $ git branch -av

Comment: added git config file

Answer (score 2):

You can control this behavior with the Git `push.default` config setting.

Sounds like value you want is `simple`. `simple` will push the current branch to its remote branch of the same name. You can set it like this:

`git config --global push.default simple`

To see all of the options for `push.default`, check out the [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) (search for "push.default").

Comment: I agree `simple` is a good setting here.  It seems odd though: the possibilities are `nothing` (which would error out), `current`, `upstream`, `simple`, and `matching`.  If the OP has the old default of `matching`, though, this should (most likely) attempt to push `develop`, since there is an `origin/develop`.  It would only behave this way if there is no `develop` on `origin`, so that there is nothing to match.  Hence "it seems odd"...

Comment: @torek Agreed, seems odd to me as well. I figured explaining `simple` was worthwhile, but there still may be more debugging necessary to fix the OP's problem.